# Binding handler 'value is not a function' knockoutJS

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, data-binding, bindinghandlers

I am stumped as to what is causing the problem here as this binding handler normally works fine (below)

```
ko.bindingHandlers.buttonGroupChecked = {
init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
    var value = valueAccessor();
    var newValueAccessor = function() {
        return {
            click: function() {
                value(allBindingsAccessor.get('val'));
            }
        };
    };
    ko.bindingHandlers.event.init(element, newValueAccessor,
            allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext);
},
update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor,
        viewModel, bindingContext) {
    if (allBindingsAccessor.get("val") === ko.unwrap(valueAccessor())) {
        helpers.activeClassSingle(element, "btn-info", "btn-success");
    }


}
};
```

I keep getting an error at line 7 `value(allBindingsAccessor.get('val'));` saying value is not a function?

The options are defined in my viewmodel as follows:-

```
self.yesNoOptions = [
    {val: 1, text: "Yes"},
    {val: 0, text: "No"}
];
```

And the corresponding HTML and binding is:-

```
<div class="btn-group btn-group-justified" data-bind="foreach: $root.yesNoOptions">
               <div class="btn btn-lg btn-info" data-bind="buttonGroupChecked: $root.currentVariation().variationAgreed, val: val, text: text"></div>
            </div>
```

Where `$root.currentVariation().variationAgreed` is an item that is currently selected and is an observable as part of the following object.

```
var observableWorkItemVariation = function(data){
var self = this;
data = data || {};
self.id = ko.observable(data.id || "");
self.orderWorkItemID = ko.observable(data.orderWorkItemID || "");
self.variationAgreed = ko.observable(data.variationAgreed || 0);
self.changeWorkBillable = ko.observable(data.changeWorkBillable || 1);
self.declareBillable = ko.observable(data.declareBillable || 0);

self.changeWorkBillable.subscribe(function(val){
   if(self.changeWorkBillable() == 0){
       self.declareBillable(0);
   } 
});

self.changeWorkPayable = ko.observable(data.changeWorkPayable || 1);
self.variationCode = ko.observable(data.variationCode || "");
}
```

It is correctly highlighting the selected item (No as it is defaulted to 0) but when I try to change it throws the error.

Comment: can you give us a sample fiddle with code .

Comment: After you assign value, take a look at what it is: `console.debug("Value:", value);` Is it a function?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `value` is out of scope when the `click` even is fired.

As it stands now you're defining `value` in the local scope of one function and you're then trying to access it later in the local scope of a different function.

I'd recommend using `click` binding directly on each div. Knockout will automatically pass you an instance of the ViewModel that was clicked, so you can use that inside of the click handler on the $root view model to figure out which button was clicked to make it active.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for the suggestions, roy gave a useful comment.

The problem was that I was creating an object from another object and I was passing variables in as varName instead of varName() to get the value (or ko.toJS(object)) so it was passing the observable through as the value of the observable.

I struggled to spot this as if you do ko.toJS() on the viewModel in `<pre>` tags it will unwrap it and show the value as correct.

Hope that is clear for anyone experiencing the problem as well.